# pandas.DataFrame.to_sql - column order of source csv file and destination table

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, azure-sql-database

In a notebook inside Azure Databricks, I am loading data from a CSV file to an Azure SQL database table by using [`pandas.DataFrame.to_sql`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html). The column order in both the CSV file and the SQL table is exactly the same. But their names are different.

**Question**: would `pandas.DataFrame.to_sql` still load the data correctly to the corresponding columns? For example, if CSV file has columns `F_Name`, `L_Name`, `Age`, `Gender` - and the SQL table has columns (in same order) as `fname`, `lname`, `person_age`, `sex`, will the data still be loaded in the same order (that is, first name column values in CSV file will go to fist name column of sql table, last name column value of CSV file will go to last name column of sql table etc...).

**Remarks**: The csv file has about 150 columns, and SQL table has exactly same number of columns. The csv file is loaded from an external source on regular basis with same number of columns in exact same order but the column names sometimes very slightly `column1` vs. `coluumn_1`, .... etc. So we don't have control over their column names (although the order is always the same first name, last name, age,...)

**Code snippet**

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy as sq
.............

pandasDFrame = pd.read_csv('/dbfs/FileStore/tables/MyFile.csv', header='infer')

pandasDFrame .to_sql(name='MySQLTable', con=engine, if_exists='replace', method='multi', chunksize=1000, index=False,\
dtype={'fname': sq.VARCHAR(15),\
     'lname': sq.VARCHAR(15),\                                                                                      
     `person_age`: sq.varchar(3),\
     `sex` : sq.varchar(10)})
```

Comment: I'd think so, yes.

Comment: Column names must match source and destination. In fact, you can test it yourself. What happens with your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider retrieving the destination table columns and assign it to your data frame before appending data frame to table:

```py
with engine.begin() as conn:
    result = conn.execute("SELECT TOP 0 * FROM MySQLTable")
    cols = [col for col in result.keys()]

pandasDFrame.columns = cols

pandasDFrame.to_sql(
    name = 'MySQLTable', 
    con = engine, 
    if_exists = 'replace', 
    method = 'multi', 
    chunksize = 1000, 
    index = False,
    dtype = {
        'fname': sq.VARCHAR(15),
        'lname': sq.VARCHAR(15),
        'person_age': sq.varchar(3),
        'sex': sq.varchar(10)
    }
)
```